# Send Log file with email? Unity

Tags: c#, email, unity-game-engine, io

I'm using Unity and C#
I want to send the output log file to my email at runtime, I used  ByteSheep answer from [this question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/433283/how-to-send-email-with-c.html) and ArkaneX comment from [this question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/433283/how-to-send-email-with-c.html) to attach a txt file, now I was successful at sending txt files but how can I send the log file? I used this code to set the path to the log `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\Unity\Editor\Editor.log"` and it does get the correct path, the problem is I'm getting

```
IOException: Sharing violation on path
```

when `System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(attachmentPath);` is called.

I think I need o close the log file first but is that even possible?
maybe a solution would be duplicating the log file and sending the new one? would that work? if so how?

Any help is apprechiated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Just a fyi you should use `Path.Combine(` instead of + to build the path. Remove the leading \ when you do.

Comment: Unity is located in your program files folder, which usually has some sort of privacy restriction on it.  I would check to see if the viewing permissions on Unity's application path are correct.  Set the permissions on Unity's folder so that everyone has read access.

Comment: The file is probably open elsewhere already.

Comment: @Scott Did not work, still gives me IOException: Sharing violation on path

Comment: I didn't say it would fix your problem, if it would i would have posted it as an answer instead of a comment. I was just showing you the proper way to do it.

Comment: @Scott Alright then, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar situation and came up with below code. As the log file is in use by the program, I'm creating a copy of it and sending it as an email attachment.

```
private string logFilePathS = @Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\logs\log.txt";
private string logFilePathD = @Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\logs\log-" + String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", DateTime.Now) + ".txt";

File.Copy(logFilePathS, logFilePathD, true);
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(logFilePathD));
```

Once the email is sent, you can delete the new file created.

```
File.Delete(logFilePathD);
```